# Impossible to type the percentage character in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Sure it's silly, but I can't find the solution.
I can't type the percentage character in the visual studio code editor.
It does not matter the programming language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you try? What happens when you try twice? What happens when you try once and then press space key?

Comment: Nothing, if I press space after, a space is typed.

Comment: Maybe percent key is bound to something. See if you can find it, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Comment: Maybe you have some extension installed that changed the key bindings (like Vim).

Comment: [Update] I search in Key Bindings and a message of Emmet plugin. I dissable the plugin and now when I type % i receive the message: 
command 'editor.emmet.action.matchTag' not found
you know how to follow?

Comment: Finally, a Key Binding for Emmet is Shift + 5 that is the % in spanish keyboard, I changed the Key Binding. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but hey, maybe it helps someone else.

'shift+5' is bound to something in Emmet. To fix this, go to Keyboard Shortcuts, in the filter field there is a small keyboard icon on the right, click on the icon it will show "Recording keystrokes", then type shift+5, in the list it will show what is bound to that (should be Emmet keybinding) right click on the keybinding row, choose Unbind.